# Print from one column when word contain in other column

Tags: python

I have a text file with 3 columns: Name, Age and Language. I want to print all the names where language column is "fr".

For example: **the text file contain Tab delimiter.**

```
Name    Age    Language
Chris    23       fr
Joe      45       de
Henri    32       eng
Samuel   65       fr
```

Desired output:

```
Chris, Samuel
```

This is my code:

```
import csv
with open('people.txt', 'r') as file:
    names = [cols[0] for cols in csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t")]
    lang = [cols[2] for cols in csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t")]
    for i,row in lang:
        if "fr" in row:
            print(names[i])
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your code? I don't see a question in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Note that you only need to open your csv file using `csv.reader` once, then iterate through all the rows, and if the third row is `fr`, append the value of first row to a list

```
import csv

names = []
with open('graph.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t")
    next(reader)
    #Iterate through all rows in csv
    for row in reader:
        #If the third element is fr
        if row[2] == 'fr':
            #Append name to names list
            names.append(row[0])

print(names)
```

The output will be

```
['Chris', 'Samuel']
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to use external modules I would tackle this task using `numpy` following way:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('data.csv',str,delimiter='\t')
names = list(data[data[:,2]=='fr'][:,0])
print(names) #prints ['Chris', 'Samuel']
```

I used [numpy.loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to get array of `str`s, informing it that file is delimited with tabs (`\t`), then I get rows, where `2`nd column (counting from zero) is `fr` and then I get values at `0`th column of these rows, i.e. names.